# Are there any electrical components which may keep electricity inside them after the device is turned off?

Tags: power, components, electricity

Is there any electrical component where electricity may remain after a device is turned off?

Comment: yes, incl. battery and HV caps

Comment: Capacitors too.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 any good way to get rid of electricity in them?

Comment: Consumer designs usually add bleeder R to limit power wasted but  Service warnings exist for inside repairs.

Comment: Well, one could also think of an electric motor with some non-negligible inertia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, called capacitors and if you are going to open a device which has them in, it is a good idea to know how to discharge them - usually through a spare resistor - and then check with a voltmeter to make sure...

Edit based on comment: There can be batteries either for keeping clocks etc running ie low power or sufficient to completely power the device.

Comment: Ok, thanks you :)

Comment: And batteries ...